# How to detect sameness or repeating data patterns in a dataset (python)

Tags: python, diff

How can I detect repeating chunks of data in a big dataset?

For example:
I have a measurement dataset of values measured on a given day for a year. Say 10 measurements a second.
And now I want to make sure that each dataset is unique. Due to Noise in a measurement even the same input will lead to numerically very different datasets.

But this seems not to be the case with the given dataset. E.g. plotting signals shows repeating patterns that are statistically extremely unlikely.

The problem reminds me of a diff from two text files. Is there any library/ established approach to this problem?

Edit: Data Structure is a csv:

```
Time (Seconds) | Sensor1 (Volt) | Sensor 2 (Volt) | ... | Sensor 10 (Volt)
```

I want to detect something like this:

```
Time (Seconds) | Sensor1 (Volt) | Sensor 2 (Volt) | ... | Sensor 10 (Volt)
1 | 242.2 | 234.23 |...|
2 | 423.23| 33.00 |...|
3 | 100.00| 24.23  |...|
```

...

```
123 | 242.2 | 234.23 |...|
124 | 423.23| 33.00 |...|
125 | 100.00| 24.23  |...|
```

Result I am looking for:

There is a repeating pattern for x timesteps. The biggest same data set is from ... to .... Second biggest from ... to ...

Comment: The data is stored in a csv file, so a table. The Rows is time of measurement, Columns are signal values. There are many columns with signals.

Comment: Load your datas into a numpy array and use numpy.unique to filter duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a package going in the right direction: https://stumpy.readthedocs.io
Motif detection is the topic.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility if your recurring patterns are really identical is to use a suffix tree or suffix array.
It will tell you which patterns are repeated, their lengths and the position of each occurrence.

In python: [Suffix arrays: How to compute them fast with Python](https://louisabraham.github.io/notebooks/suffix_arrays.html)